# Wordpress Child Theme Needs to pull Multiple style sheets form Parent

Tags: php, css, wordpress, parent-child

I am putting together a wordpress child theme based on a parent theme that has multiple style sheets in it's directory. So for example this is the navigation to a few of the style sheets:

- parent-theme/style.css
- parent-theme/css/style.css
- parent-theme/css/bootstrap.css

I created my child folder and created my style.css file as well as my function.php file but it seems that the child theme is only pulling the style sheet for the parent-theme/style.css file and not pulling all the .css files.

After doing some digging this is where my functions.php file is at currently:

```
<?php

/* v1.0.5
Date: 5/15/17
*/


function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'wizard-style'; // This is 'wizard' for the Wizard theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

My main objective is to have the child theme pull all needed stylesheets and utilize the one single style sheet under my child them folder (child-theme/style.css) for any changes I would like to make.

My questions are:

1. Is this possible?

   - If it is possible, what errors may be occurring that is causing my fucntion.php file not to pull all the stylesheets?
   - If it is not possible, what changes do I need to make to my function.php file and my directory to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this with ArileWP theme, after a lot of research I figured out that loading multiple style sheets was not the issue (using the enqueue function on wordpress.org forums and other forums did in fact load all stylesheets regardless of whether they were in the root level or lower directory levels of the parent theme).

The issue in my case ended up being that Arile requires you to install their "arile extra" plugin, and this plugin has an if statement that is conditional on what your child theme is named:

```
if( 'ArileWP' == $activate_theme || 'Business Street' == $activate_theme || 'StrangerWP' == $activate_theme || 'NewYork City' == $activate_theme || 'InteriorPress' == $activate_theme || 'Arile WP Child' == $activate_theme ){
        require("inc/arilewp/arilewp.php");
```

Their plugin has a default name Arile WP Child that, if you are not using as the name of your child theme, the extra features included in the plugin will not execute.

The cleanest solution in my case was to simply change the name of my child theme to the one defaulted in their php file.

Might not be the same issue you are having but was a simple fix that just took me a long time to narrow down.

Answer (score 0):

Check the page 'view source' to make sure the style sheets are being loaded from the parent. When you activate a child theme its still pulling everything from the parent unless you override the specific file (example: header.php).

The functions.php and style.css files are the only exception as they supplement their corresponding parent theme file.

So, in summary those stylesheets should be included on your websites. Your theme settings may be incorrect but if you're in a pinch and just need to get those style sheets loaded just add them manually via the functions.php file by 
[enqueuing them](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

EDIT: 
Does the child theme stylesheet contain the following commented out information customized for your theme, of course?

/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    URI
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/

If it isn't overriding the parent the styles it could possibly be a cache issue. If you don't have any cache plugins it could be your hosting environment or Cloudflare. If you can clear the server cache then refresh your browser with a Cntrl+F5 and see if that helps.

Did you try adding !important to your child styles for troubleshooting purposes already? Does your theme have a custom style option that lets to save styles to the database that it loads with each page to override the parent theme? Its not ideal but works if youre in a pinch.

Sorry if I am telling you elementary things I am not sure what your experience level is.

Comment: All the style sheets do load, the issue is that the child style sheet is not overriding the additional parent style sheets (the style sheets located under the /css/ folder) but only the style sheet located in the main directory.

Comment: See my edits. Also, comment out the enqueuing of the parent theme styles in the child functions.php right now because adding them in after the child style loads may override the child.

Comment: /*
Theme Name: Wizard Child
Theme URI: http://frgraphicsolutions.com/wizard-child
Description: Wizard Child Theme
Author: Fraga Graphic Solutions
Author URI: frgraphicsolutions.com
Template: wizard
Version: 1.0.1
File Name: style.css
File Location: /css/
*/

Comment: "If it isn't overriding the parent the styles it could possibly be a cache issue." - This is not the case, I have been clearing my cache as well as using an incognito tab. "Did you try adding !important to your child styles for troubleshooting purposes already?" - I have not tried this, I can try but I would have to add that to every element wouldn't I? "Does your theme have a custom style option that lets to save styles to the database that it loads with each page to override the parent theme" - I think it does but shouldn't I be utilizing a child theme instead?

Comment: The !Important element would just be to make sure the child theme is loading and available as a resource. If they are loading which it sounds like they are it might be an order of loading problem.

If youre not aware, CSS works based on an principle that the "further away" the style is from the element the less priority it has. A style.css external file is lower priority to style tags on the page which is lower priority than inline element styles. !Important overrides this principle

Comment: The child theme is preferable to loading those styles from the options table in the database but the latter still works. It may slow down your page loads slightly if the styles loaded from the DB are bloated and not minified after being saved.

Comment: Dan, the !important works but doesn't this bog down my website? I thought the point of the function.php file in the child theme was to prevent a "CSS file needlessly being loaded twice" based on wordpresses codex. I am a beginner and only have done a few sites but all my previous sites I just needed the function.php file and style.css file in my child theme and any code written in the style.css file of the child theme was by default loaded first without the need for the !important. The only difference with this new theme I am working on is that the parent theme has multiple style.css files.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve the same result when the parent has multiple style sheets buy utilizing php coding in my child theme?

Comment: Is the site youre working on available for me to look at? I can take a look and see what is going on

In your question it looks like youre enqueuing the parent styles in your child theme? This might be causing the issue. You do not need to enqueue those stylesheets. They will already be loaded in. If you're loading them again it probably loads after the child stylesheet and overrides it.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an element that is not pulling from the child style so I can focus on that. I should be able to figure out from that

Comment: Dan, It seems that I might be having some sort of cache problem after all. Looks like there are multiple places where I need to clear the cache (including possible plugins keeping cache data) and no real way to truly clear it even when using the incognito browser. Without that updating I can't tell if any changes I am making are working/not working. Do you have any tips other than clearing history to force the website data to clear? This has become a nightmare.

Comment: Incognito prevents browser level caching but your server, Wordpress, and plugins cache is a bit different. One tip, always be logged in to Wordpress as you're editing. Logged in users typically do not get served cached content. Also, set any cache plugins to development mode if that is an option. It will prevent this. Your ISP may even cache beyond your server, website, Cloudflare, and browser so check if your work or home internet provider caches data as well and ask them to whitelist websites you are working on.

Comment: Dan - an update - I am finally able to clear my cache properly and I am working with the developer on this issue.

It seems to me after digging deep on the internet no one seems to know how to create a child theme based on a parent theme with multiple Style sheets. Not even the support team of the people who created the parent theme can manage to write a function.php file that properly enqueues all corresponding style sheets of the child them and allows editing of the child theme's style sheets to trump the parent's style sheet. 
If you have any other insight that would be much appreciated.